# how can i configure sgml-mode to format open and close tags on same line?

Tags: formatting, xml

I set up my emacs to use sgml-mode so that I can format xml with `M-x reformat-xml`, but it puts the closing tags on the line below, rather than on the same line.

instead of this:

```
<mytag>stuff
</mytag>
```

I want this:

```
<mytag>stuff</mytag>
```

Can I configure `sgml-mode` to do this for all reformats?

So far I've just got this to activate `sgml-mode`:

```
(require 'sgml-mode)

(defun reformat-xml ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (sgml-pretty-print (point-min) (point-max))
    (indent-region (point-min) (point-max))))
```